# Reactivecocoa doesn't recognize new instance changes

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Say I have a View that is bonded to his ViewModel like so:

View:

```
RAC(self.lbl, userName) = RACObserve(self.viewModel.user, userName);
```

This will work great! but what happens in cases when I load a new User instance and set it like so:

ViewModel:

```
-(void) userUpdated: (User *) user {

self.user =  user;

}
```

In this case, the views binding will still be bonded to the old user instance! Did any one come across this and find a better way to solve this except setting all properties of the old user with the new ones...?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RAC(self.lbl, userName) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, user.userName);
```

The comma denotes the break between the "static" part (`self.viewModel`) and the dynamic, changing part (`user.userName`).

This is a really nice feature of `RACObserve`, but you *could* implement this yourself, to modify Leo's answer so that it works with a changing `userName`: `map` not into the username, but into a *signal* of usernames, and then "flatten" that with `switchToLatest`:

```
RAC(self.lbl, userName) = [[RACObserve(self.viewModel, user) map:^(User *user) {
    return RACObserve(user, userName);
}] switchToLatest];
```

This simple example isn't very useful, since `RACObserve` has this built in, but this technique in general is extremely powerful. You will eventually want to map into signals of not-observed-things, so I encourage you to take the time to understand why this works.

Comment: First, Thank you for your time! This is perfect!! Second, I do not understand why will I use the second example for this case.. The first one does the job just fine... Second one is just longer, and I'm getting a Signal at the fist one too... So I'm confused about that one...

Comment: @PiratM Like I said, you wouldn't use this *if you're observing*. But what if you you're interested in `textSignal` of a changing `textView`? You can't `RACObserve(self, textView.text)`, because `UITextView` isn't KVO-compliant for `text`. Instead, you have to `[[RACObserve(self, textView) map:^(UITextView *textView) { return textView.textSignal; }] switchToLatest];`. It's the general case of the special shorthand that `RACObserve` gives you.

Comment: @lan Henry Got it! Thanks once again!!